# C# Background worker setting e.Result in DoWork and getting value back in WorkCompleted

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

C# 2008 SP1

I am using the background worker

If one of the conditions fails I will set e.cancel to true, and assign the string to the e.result. Everything works there.

However, when the workCompleted fires, I test for the e.Result and I get an exception "e.result throw an exception of type systeminvalidoperation".

I guess I could use a global variable to set in the DoWork and compare in the work completed. But this might not be threadsafe.

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this with the e.Result, and how can I solve this?

Many thanks,

```
    private void bgwPrepareCall_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if the called number is blocked. 
        // If the nubmer is blocked display error message.
        if (this.IsNoGateway(sipUsername, statusDisplay1.PhoneNumber))
        {
            // this.SetIdleState(DialerErrorMessage.GetErrorDescription(12));
            e.Cancel = true;
            e.Result = "NoGateway";
            return;
        }

        if (!this.IsInvalidTelephoneNumber(sipUsername, statusDisplay1.PhoneNumber))
        {
            // this.SetIdleState(DialerErrorMessage.GetErrorDescription(13));
            e.Cancel = true;
            e.Result = "InvalidNumber";
            return;
        }
    }

    private void bgwPrepareCall_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Failed
                switch (e.Result.ToString())
                {
                    case "NoGateway":
                        Console.WriteLine("NoGateway: [ Failed ]");
                        break;

                    case "InvalidNumber":
                        Console.WriteLine("InvalidNumber: [ Failed ]");
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Successfull
                Console.WriteLine("NoGateway: [ ok ]");    
                Console.WriteLine("InvalidNumber: [ ok ]");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PrepareCall Failed: [ " + e.Error.Message + " ]");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx):

> If the operation completes
>   successfully and its result is
>   assigned in the DoWork event handler,
>   you can access the result through the
>   RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result
>   property.

[and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx):

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler
>   should always check the Error and
>   Cancelled properties before accessing
>   the Result property. If an exception
>   was raised or if the operation was
>   canceled, accessing the Result
>   property raises an exception.

So if it *doesn't* complete successfully (i.e. you cancel it) it looks like it won't work. Perhaps consider returning your cancellation-details as the result (as success) for your abort case, an detecting the difference in the completion handler?

Answer (score 19):

The `Result` property is meant to represent the result of a *completed* operation. You've set `Cancel` to true, meaning that the operation was cancelled, therefore there shouldn't be a result.

It sounds like you should encode the "I aborted because something was wrong" into your result, or throw an exception which will be set as the `Error` property in the result instead - `Cancel` is meant to be set if the worker noticed that the call was cancelled externally.

The docs for [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx) state:

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler
>   should always check the Error and
>   Cancelled properties before accessing
>   the Result property. If an exception
>   was raised or if the operation was
>   canceled, accessing the Result
>   property raises an exception.

The "Exceptions" part of the documentation also states that it will throw an exception if `Cancelled` is true.

Answer (score 2):

It's most probably because the code Cancels the work instead of completing it. So try accessing the result in the if(!e.Cancel) branch.