# How to use the BackgroundWorker event RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

All,I already knew the basic usage the `BackgroundWorker` to handle multiple thread case in the WinForm . And the code structure looks like below.

In the main thread of application. just start the BackgroundWork.

```
    if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
    {
        // Start the asynchronous operation.
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Then it would fire the `DoWork` event . So we can do something in there.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    ......
    // report progress.
    worker.ReportProgress(iProgress);
    ....
}
```

Then we just need to handle the `ProgressChanged` event to show the BackgroundWorker progress.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //show progress.   
    resultLabel.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
}
```

After `DoWork` finished or some exception happened. the event `RunWorkerCompleted` would be fired.

Here comes my questions for this events handle. please help to review them. thanks.

I noticed there is property named 'Result' in the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e`, What does it use for? How can I use it ?

Is there any possibility to receive my custom exception message instead the `e.error`? If there is, How to make it ?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled == true)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        resultLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Result` property in `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` is the value you have assigned to the Result property of `DoWorkEventHandler` in `DoWork()`.

You can assign anything you like to this, so you could return an integer, a string, an object/composite type, etc.

If an exception is thrown in `DoWork()` then you can access the exception in the `Error` property of `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`. In this situation, accessing the Result property will cause an `TargetInvocationException` to be thrown.

Comment: What about `Error`? this is also what the OP asked for.

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks. (Reading on phone and missed it)

Answer (score 7):

```
public class MyWorkerClass
{
    private string _errorMessage = "";
    public string ErrorMessage { get { return _errorMessage; } set { _errorMessage = value; }}

    public void RunStuff(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //... put some code here and fill ErrorMessage whenever you want
    }
}
```

then the class where you use it

```
public class MyClassUsingWorker
{
    // have reference to the class where the worker will be running
    private MyWorkerClass mwc = null;

    // run the worker
    public void RunMyWorker()
    {
        mwc = new MyWorkerClass();
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(mwc.RunStuff);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string strSpecialMessage = mwc.ErrorMessage;

        if (e.Cancelled == true)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Error: " + e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            resultLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Result property to store any results from the DoWork and access it from Completed event. But if the background worker process got cancelled or an exception raised, the result won't be accessible. You will find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856313/c-sharp-background-worker-setting-e-result-in-dowork-and-getting-value-back-in-w).