# c# wait for background worker to complete task

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

So I have a background worker which carries out a task and I need the program to wait for this task to be completed before continuing, at the moment I'm doing this:

```
while(backgroundwork.IsBusy)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

however when I run this the program just stops running, seems like the background worker is running constantly but it isn't, there's no looping in the worker and it's finished its tasks before.

what could I have missed?

Comment: is anything stopping you to use background worker completed event?

Comment: might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316613/when-should-taskcompletionsourcet-be-used

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` will cause the current thread (i.e. the foreground thread) to sleep. While it's sleeping, it ain't doing anything else. Show your code for how you create the background worker.

Comment: The whole point of the background worker is that the UI thread **does not wait for it to complete**. If you do that, you might just as well call the code directly instead of through a background worker. The correct way to use a background worker is to subscribe to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and do whatever needs to be done in the UI after the task has finished **there**.

Comment: @Heinzi that commment could be the answer in my opinion. Although you cannot really answer an incomplete question :(

Comment: As pointed out in a few comments, `BackgroundWorker` looks a bit fishy :)
It's obsolete in current version of C# since you have more flexible async patterns at your disposal - maybe point out what you want to achieve, and we can come up with a better solution?

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that help understand your question? Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: The real issue here is why you want to 'wait', and what that should mean. Do you want to block certain UI features? etc.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that my progress bar wasn't empty until the task was completed. I just added another update before my task started to paint the bar halfway. All good now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event. You can wait on a WaitHandle (like [autoresetevent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)), and signal that from RunWorkerCompleted event.

Answer (score 1):

**[Thread.Sleep](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_sleep_millis.htm)** is used to wait for specified time and do nothing.

**[Async wait](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async)** is used to wait until given task gets completed.

> `myMethod().wait()` - here myMethod would be your async method and
>   `wait()` is c# keyword which will wait asynchronous for that method to
>   be completed.

see the difference between thread.sleep() and Async delay - [**Here!!**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx)

Comment: what's myMethod? (sorry I haven't been programming for very long)

Comment: myMthod() is your method containing piece of code which you needed -  to wait for task to be completed.

Comment: it's in a button click event?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

As [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87698/heinzi) stated in a comment, you should just use the RunWorkerCompleted event.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723742/how-to-use-the-backgroundworker-event-runworkercompleted) is an good example on "how to use the backgroundworker runworkercompleted event" You shall never "wait" for a task/thread to finish, but you could "wait" for waithandles or let the thread do other stuff in the meantime

> In the Class where you hold an instance of the
>   [Backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   you can simply **attach to the completed event** and your fine.
>
> Delete that loop with the Thread.Sleep() in it

.

```
private void WorkerExample() {
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += OnWorkerCompleted; //listen for that event by attaching a handler
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

//This is the EventHandler
private void OnWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs) {
    //This method is called, when the worker finished his job
}
```

### Further Information:

There are also some more useful events on the BackgroundWorker.

[image: Backgroundworker events]

[MSDN provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) a complete example how to use the BackgroundWorker. You should have a look at that.